# mod_rewrite Remove .php from specific file and prevent access to the original file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to change:

```
www.foo.com/bar.php
```

To:

```
www.foo.com/bar
```

And after that, prevent direct access to /bar.php but allow /bar:

```
www.foo.com/bar.php    404 Not Found
```

I want access to bar.php to give a 404 error.
Basically, I want it to look like "bar" is a directory.

Is this even possible?

My current code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^bar/?$ bar.php [NC]
```

Comment: Your "current code" already appears to do the main part - any problem with this? Presumably the URL has already been changed to `/bar` in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
#prevent direct access to /bar.php
#return a 404 error if /bar.php is direct accessed
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /bar\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
#rewrite /bar to /bar.php
#this will internally forward http://example.com/bar to http://example.com/bar.php
RewriteRule ^bar$ /bar.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Just a question, what does the [L] flag do? The NC flag seems to work aswell

Comment: @SveaNils https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l